# How best to make "accessable" File I/O Stream constructors (channel & ByteBuffer also)

Tags: java, io

I'd like to know how best to make "accessable" or "visible" a set of File I/O Stream constructors defined in my main routine, to sub-routines.

I found that I cannot use "public", the compiler issues an "Illegal Expression" error msg.

When I place the file I/O stream and channel constructors in the public class defined for 
the entire program "package".  The compiler issues an error stating there's no FileNotFound or IOException handling declared, so I put on my mainline routine the following:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
 { 
     // and if I then place the File I/O contructors after this: 

                   //Connect to the LU62XC Message File 
    FileOutputStream MesgOut = new FileOutputStream(Mesg_File) ;
    FileChannel MesgChnl  =  MesgOut.getChannel() ;
    ByteBuffer  Mesg_Bufr =  ByteBuffer.allocate(128) ; 

           //Connect to the Request Input File 
    FileInputStream RqstInp = new FileInputStream(Rqst_File) ;  
           //Connect to the Response Output File 
    FileOutputStream RespOut = new FileOutputStream(Resp_File) ;
           //Connect to the Request/Response Log File 
    FileOutputStream LogrOut = new FileOutputStream(Logr_File) ;
```

I resolve the "no exception handling error", but now my problem is the sub-routines
that reference the "constructed" file objects essentianlly can't .. I get a bunch of 
"symbol not found" error messages. Again, if I put "public" in front of the file I/O constructors, I get the Illegal expression message.

Is there any way out of this ???

Why the java compiler insists on the program handling file-not-found errors is beyond me. 
I mean there's already the if `file_object.exists()` method...

IF the file's NOT there.. the OS will let you know. All ANY application program(OOP or otherwise) does when it comes to I/O of any kind is to make a request to the underlying OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a method to use an object you have as a local variable you can pass its as an argument.  This is standard practice in just about every language I can think of.  However instead of passing the FileInputStream it is better to pass the file name in camelCase

```
// in main
process(requestFile, responseFile, logFile);

// later
public static void process(String requestFile, String responseFile, String logFile) throw IOException {
    //Connect to the Request Input File 
    FileInputStream requestIn = new FileInputStream(requestFile);  
    //Connect to the Response Output File 
    FileOutputStream responseOut = new FileOutputStream(responseFile);
    //Connect to the Request/Response Log File 
    FileOutputStream logOut = new FileOutputStream(logFile);

    requestIn.close();
    responseOut.close();
    logOut.close();
}
```

> I get a bunch of "symbol not found" error messages.

Because a local variable is local to the scope i.e. the method it is in. You can't use it in another method.

> Again, if I put "public" in front of the file I/O constructors, I get the Illegal expression message.

Because public fields cannot be defined in a method, they have to be define outside a method, usually at the start of the class.

> Is there any way out of this ???

Reading a few tutorials http://www.google.com/search?q=java+turorials 11 million results, or working example http://www.google.com/search?q=java+examples 25 million results

> Why the java compiler insists on the program handling file-not-found errors is beyond me. I mean there's already the If file_object.exists() method... IF the file's NOT there..the OS will let you know.

It does let you know by throwing a FileNotFoundException. What do you expect it to do?

> All ANY application program(OOP or otherwise) does when it comes to I/O of any kind is to make a request to the underlying OS.

And the OS can return an error which you need to be able to handle.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks very much for your insight. However, what I meant was I don't see the need for the compiler to reject the code because one doesn't have a "File-Not-Found" "handler". Take COBOL for instance. While COBOL will return File I/O exceptions to the calling application, IF you don't code any File I/O exception logic, the COBOL compiler doesn't "reject" your code.  I think that's where the java compiler goes "overboard"... runtime exceptions... the compiler should ONLY check syntax.

Comment: @Guy Rich, Many people agree with you. However from years of working with checked exception I would much prefer the compiler force you to think about and address in code certain errors which can occur. You only need to throw or catch IOException (as its a super class of FileNotFoundException) and a decent IDE can make it much easier to manage your exceptions so it not as much an overhead that it used to me. I can understand developers not wanting to think about error handling, but that just tell me its a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic Java: you have to pass references the methods that need them, or create them as instance variables and instantiate a class.

I suggest you read the "Getting Started" tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Comment: Hello Anon ... well I've seen a lot of these turorials  it's "Hello World" ad nauseum.... While they're a good starting point, they're a little "light" on best practices and techniques.